# Editor giving "Unexpected End Tag" syntax error for HTML file

Tags: html, editor, syntax-error, komodoedit

Edit: Because of the time restriction of the project I just had to revert to a working copy of the code and redo all my work, but I would still like to know what the reason is for this for the future.

So, I've had this problem now for a little while, of one of the dags in this HTML file I've been working on where a from and div tags would get underlined by my editor (Komodo) saying something to the effect of "Unexpected End Tag (ignored). This wasn't causing much problems so I just ignored it...until the editor started highlighting the closing body tag with the same thing and the file doesn't actually work correctly (using JQM) anymore.

The thing I don't understand is that I haven't been touching the HTML AT ALL. In the past when this happened (as it has before), I just pulled a previous version from the repo I'm using and that would resolve the issue, but this time I haven't made a commit in a while and I really want to find a solution to this problem rather than a quick fix.

Here is a screenshot of the syntax error I'm getting via my editor:

[image]

Here is the HTML for the form, if it matters:

```
        <div data-role="content">
                        <img src="img/logo.png" alt="RPG Tracker">
        <form action="" method="post" id="addCharForm">
            <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
                <label for="dateCreated">Date Created:</label>
            <input type="date" name="dateCreated" id="dateCreated">
        </fieldset>

        <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
                <label for="charAge">Age:</label>
            <input type="text" name="charAge" id="charAge" value="" class="required number">
        </fieldset>

        <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
            <label for="charName">Name:</label>
            <input type="text" name="charName" id="charName" value="" class="required">
        </fieldset>

        <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
            <legend>Choose character gender:</legend>
            <input type="radio" name="gender" id="radioMale" value="Male">
            <label for="radioMale">Male</label>

            <input type="radio" name="gender" id="radioFemale" value="Female">
            <label for="radioFemale">Female</label>
        </fieldset>

        <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
            <label for="charAttrs">Describe your character's <b>attributes</b> in this field:</label>
            <textarea id="charAttrs" name="charAtts"></textarea>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
            <label for="charSkills">Describe your character's <b>skills</b> in this field:</label>
            <textarea id="charSkills" name="charSkills"></textarea>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
            <label for="charBio">Character Biography:</label>
            <textarea id="charBio" name="charBio"></textarea>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
            <label for="charRating">Rate Your Character:</label>
            <input type="range" name="charRating" id="charRating" value="100" min="0" max="100">
        </fieldset>

        <input type="reset" value="Reset">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit Character" data-theme="b">
        </form>
    </div>
```

As requested, here's the full html:
http://pastebin.com/tsE0MuP7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `input` and `img` tags are self closing, so I suggest closing them all and seeing if that fixes it. (I suspect it won't, but it's worth a try).

e.g.

```
<img src="img/logo.png" alt="RPG Tracker" />
```

and

```
<input type="date" name="dateCreated" id="dateCreated" />
```

The issue could be elsewhere in the file too, so a copy of the entire HTML would be preferable. It will probably be an open tag somewhere (e.g. using `<div>` instead of `</div>`).

Comment: Added the full html to the bottom of my question. As for the self closing tags, I didn't close any of them because if I have HTML5 selected as my language on my editor, closing those tags makes the editor say the line has a syntax error.

Comment: As suspected you have an un-closed div. Your top level div with id "home" has not been closed.

Comment: Hmm, strange...you'd think the editor would catch where the was an unbalanced number of close tags. That solved the body tag issue, so will say it's answered, but something of note is that I still get similar error in the form of said page.

Comment: What do you mean? The form is also complaining? Try commenting out the form, then introducing each element one by one.

Comment: Well, that isn't really needed, I can see just by looking at it that one of the divs isn't closed, but when I close it, it messes up one of the divs below.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
        <label for="charName">Name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="charName" id="charName" value="" class="required">
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
        <legend>Choose character gender:</legend>
        <input type="radio" name="gender" id="radioMale" value="Male">
        <label for="radioMale">Male</label>

        <input type="radio" name="gender" id="radioFemale" value="Female">
        <label for="radioFemale">Female</label>
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
        <label for="charAttrs">Describe your character's <b>attributes</b> in this field:</label>
        <textarea id="charAttrs" name="charAtts"></textarea>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
        <label for="charSkills">Describe your character's <b>skills</b> in this field:</label>
        <textarea id="charSkills" name="charSkills"></textarea>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
        <label for="charBio">Character Biography:</label>
        <textarea id="charBio" name="charBio"></textarea>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
        <label for="charRating">Rate Your Character:</label>
        <input type="range" name="charRating" id="charRating" value="100" min="0" max="100">
    </fieldset>

    <input type="reset" value="Reset">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit Character" data-theme="b">
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you explain your answer please?